# How to use tidyGeocoder with custom geocoder?

Tags: r, api, geocoding

I have the following geocoder service: https://geodata.md.gov/imap/rest/services/GeocodeServices/MD_CompositeLocator/GeocodeServer?f=pjson

I want to use this in the tidygeocoder library
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidygeocoder/vignettes/tidygeocoder.html

But I want to use the maryland geocoder instead of the Google or Censu geocoders. How would I set up the script to do this? Ideally I could add a new method of geocoding which uses the Maryland geocoder.

Answer (score 0):

There's a comprehensive list of what to do to add a new method to the package [here](https://github.com/jessecambon/tidygeocoder/issues/34). However, to start you could try using the [get_api_query](https://jessecambon.github.io/tidygeocoder/reference/get_api_query.html) and [query_api](https://jessecambon.github.io/tidygeocoder/reference/query_api.html) functions to execute a query. You'll then need to extract the relevant data from the response and put it into dataframe format (the job of the extract_results function). Good luck and feel free to file an issue or reach out if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you, I cannot figure out how to find the parameters.

Comment: Looks like the API parameter documentation for that service is here: https://geodata.md.gov/imap/sdk/rest/index.html#//02ss00000029000000